# Why call SqlClient.SqlDataReader Close() method anyway?

Tags: .net-3.5, sqlconnection

Is the SqlClient.SqlDataReader a .NET managed object or not?
Why do we have to call the Close() method explicitly close an open connection?
Shouldn't running out of scope for such an object automatically close this?
Shouldn't garbage collector clean it up anyway?

Please help me understand what is the best practise here.

I have seen a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247311/sqldatareader-in-this-scenario-will-the-reader-get-closed) and it further illustrates the issue I have with a web application. The issue is that we were running out of connections. The detailed error is here:

```
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.
Source: System.Data 

at  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionPoolManager.GetPooledConnection(SqlConnectionString options, Boolean& isInTransaction)
at  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
```

To fix this, I had to explicitly close all the SQLDataReader objects.

I am using .NET Framework 3.5

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Sure, it will be collected when it goes out of scope (if their are no other references to it).  When it is collected, it will be closed through its Dispose() method.  However, you never really know when the GC is going to deallocate things; if you don't close your readers, you very quickly run out of available connections to the database.

### Further Reading

- O'Reilly's [ADO.NET Connection Pool Explained](http://www.ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2004/02/09/connpool.html)
- Microsoft's [Retrieving Data using a DataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(VS.71).aspx) has a general overview of DataReaders.

~ William Riley-Land

Comment: Should mention the CommandBehavior.CloseConnection parameter option, which eliminates the latency between dispose and actual Garbage collection, when connection would be released to ADO pool

Comment: the GC doesn't call Dispose so don't count on that. It calls Finalize.

Answer (score 17):

@Lieutenant Frost

> As a rule in our shop, we explicitly
>   wrap all database calls in a
>   Try...Finally block, with the finally
>   section catching and closing the data
>   connections. It's worth the tiny bit
>   of effort to save yourself a major
>   troubleshooting headache.

I have a similar rule, but I require that objects implementing IDisposable use the 'using' block.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conStr))
{
     using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
     {
        // ETC
     } 
}
```

The using block calls Dispose immediately when leaving the scope, even with an exception.

Comment: This your rule sounds good and elegant - I should borrow for my shop

Comment: Interesting. I'll play with this and see if it'll work. I like this a lot better, anyway.

Comment: Does a using block for the DataReader have any benefit here or is the using block for the connection enough? e.g. using (IDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())

Comment: and what if the reader can not be instantiated within using block e.g. it is being passed as out parameter or being reused or ...?

Comment: Too many usings = too much confusion, IMHO. But, of course, anyone can have their preferences. And, as it has been noted, there are times that a using statement cannot be used.

Answer (score 11):

One good practice (as long as you aren't re-using connections) is to add the Command Behavior to the SqlDataReader to close the connection when it gets disposed:

```
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader( CommandBehavior.CloseConnection );
```

Adding this will ensure that the connection to the database is closed when the SqlDataReader object is closed (or garbage collected).

As I stated before, though, you don't want to do this if you are planning on re-using the database connection for another operation within the same method.

Answer (score 4):

I think everybody else said this but I wanted it to be clear:

Out of scope doesn't mean immediate garbage collection.

Your app needs to 'play nice' on a number of levels.
Closing the connections helps you do that.
Let's examine a few of those levels.

1: You aren't relying on garbage collection.
Ideally garbage collection shouldn't need to exist.  But it does.
But most assuredly you should not rely on it.

2: You aren't holding your database connections.
While connections are usually pooled, as you've found there is a limit.
Holding this longer than necessary makes your app the bad apple.

3: You aren't generating network traffic.
Every database connection is essentially a TCP connection.
Keeping it open probably generates network traffic along the lines of
Are you still there? yes.
Small traffic yes, but on a crowded network this is bad practice.
And SQL Server itself is using resources to keep your connection alive.
Resources other people trying to get to that sql server could make better use of.

When thinking about database access you also have to think about network resources.
Some ways to get the data are bad because they can bring unnecessary stuff along for the ride.  The earlier versions of ADO were kind of notorious for this type of stuff.  Bringing back the schema info when you just want the data.  Sure, with only a few connections this isn't a problem.  But since when does any database have only a few connections.  So think about this stuff and try not to abuse the resources.

When your web app only has 100 users you may not care.
But what about 100,000?  Always consider what happens when you scale.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't explicitly close it, then it sits there waiting for the garbage collector to  "collect" it... Only after that happens does it get released back to the ADO.Net Connection pool to be reused by another Connection.Open request, so during all the intervening time, any other requests for a connection will have to create a brand new one, even though there is a perfectly good one sitting there unused that could be used...

Depending on how long it is before the GC runs, and how many Database requests are being executed, you could run out of available connections to the database.

But there is a optional parameter on the Command.ExecuteReader() method, called CommandBehavior.  This is an enumeration, with values: 
CommandBehavior.Default, CommandBehavior.SingleResult, CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly, CommandBehavior.KeyInfo, CommandBehavior.SingleRow, CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess, and  CommandBehavior.CloseConnection

This enumeration has a FlagsAttribute attribute that allows a bitwise combination of its member values.  It is the last value, (CommandBehavior.CloseConnection) that is relevant here. It tells the Command object to close the connection when the data reader is closed.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandbehavior.aspx

Unfortunately the default is NOT to close the connection when the data reader is closed, but you can, (and should) pass this parameter as  CommandBehavior.CloseConnection when you want your method to release the connection back to the pool immediately when you are done with it...

Answer (score 2):

The 'managed' resource referred to by the term 'managed code' is memory.  That's it.  Any other scarce resource needs to be wrapped with the disposable pattern, including database connections.

The reason this is a problem for you is that the garbage collector doesn't run for every object the moment it goes out of scope.  It's much more efficient to collect more items less frequently.  So if you wait for the collector to dispose your objects (and yes, if you implement idisposable it eventually will) you maybe be holding a number of database connections open much longer than you realize.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the Connection that's the problem, but the SQL Cursor being held by the SqlDataReader.  If you try to open a second without closing the first, it will throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Also take into consideration what happens when an exception gets thrown - you never know if the connection will be closed if you suddenly are forced out of the executing code.

As a rule in our shop, we explicitly wrap all database calls in a Try...Finally block, with the finally section catching and closing the data connections. It's worth the tiny bit of effort to save yourself a major troubleshooting headache.

Comment: The 'using' construct is more elegant, and will guarantee the object is disposed with the same degree of certainty as 'finally'.

Comment: @Joel what is more "elegant" is, definatly, a matter of personal taste. Since both methods will dispose the object with 'the same degree of certainity'. Personally, I prefer to rely on code that _tells you_ what is doing. A using statement _does not tell you_ it is disposing and what is disposing, but, in a finally statement, you can be sure you dispose what is written there, and nothing more or less. Making assumptions is the root of many problems.

Comment: @ThunderGr I have to agree with Joel. The using statement does tell you it is disposing and what it's disposing, you just have to understand how using statements work in C#, which is probably a good idea if you're working in C#.