# Importance of closing SQLConnection objects when using the SQLDataReader object

Tags: vb.net, generics, ado.net, sqlconnection.close

My present contract engagement is at a large E-Commerce company. Their code base which has origins going back to .Net 1.0 has caught me by surprise to contain many issues that raise the level of smell beyond the last crap I took.

That notwithstanding and trying to diffuse my level of distraction from it, I go along merrily trying to add in features to either fix other problems or extend more crap. Where I touch the DAL/BLL the time it will take to fix the aforementioned will be done. However I wanted to get a vote of confidence from the experts to get some assurance of not wasting the clients time or worse having my credibility voted down by touching "stuff that works".  Of course unit testing would solve or at least soften this worry. Perhaps this should also be added to the wtf.com?

```
Public Function GetSizeInfoBySite(ByVal siteID As String) As IList
    Dim strSQL As String = "YES INLINE SQL!! :)"
    Dim ci As CrapInfo
    Dim alAnArrayList As ArrayList

    Dim cn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("ConnectionString"))
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strSQL, cn)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@MySiteID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 2)).Value = siteID
    cn.Open()
    Dim rs As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
    While rs.Read()
        ci = New CategoryInfo(rs("someID"), rs("someName"))
        If IsNothing(alAnArrayList) Then
            alAnArrayList = New ArrayList
        End If
        alAnArrayList.Add(ci)
    End While
    rs.Close()
    Return CType(alAnArrayList, IList)
End Function
```

Does anyone see problems with this aside from the inline SQL which makes my gut churn? At the least wouldn't you ordinarily wrap the above in a try/catch/finally which most of us knows has been around since .Net v1.0? Even better would'nt it be wise to fix with Using statements? Does the SQLDataReader close really encapsulate the connection close automagically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing wrong with inline sql if the user input is properly parameterized, and this looks like it is.

Other than that, yes you do need to close the connections.  On a busy web site you could hit your limit and that would cause all kinds of weirdness.

I also noticed it's still using an arraylist.  Since they've moved on from .Net 1.0 it's time to update those to generic `List<T>`'s (and avoid the call to CType- you should be able to DirectCast() that instead).

Answer (score 3):

Definitely get some using statements around the Connection and Reader objects. If there is an exception, they won't be closed until the Garbage Collector gets around to them.

I tend not to call .Close() when there are using statements. Even if the SqlDataReader closes the connection on dispose (check the doco), putting a using around the Connection can't hurt and sticks to the pattern .

If you do that the try/finally is only needed if you need to do exception handling right there. I tend to leave exception handling at the higher levels (wrap each UI entry point, Library entry points, extra info in exception) as the stacktrace is usually enough to debug the errors.

Not that it matters much, but if you are re-factoring, move the collection initialization outside the loop. On second thoughts the code returns null if there are no records.

At least SqlParameters are used! Get rid of anything that concatenates user input with SQL if you find it (SQL Injection attack) no matter how well "Cleaned" it is.

Comment: I agree.  Also, this post has some more information.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250468/why-call-sqlclientsqldatareader-close-method-anyway

Comment: Robert,
Appreciate your points on the try/catch and noting about GC potential delays!

Answer (score 3):

The connection will be closed when the reader is closed because it's using the CloseConnection command behavior.

```
Dim rs As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
```

According to MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa326246(VS.71).aspx)

> If the SqlDataReader is created with CommandBehavior set to CloseConnection, closing the SqlDataReader closes the connection automatically.

Answer (score 1):

In reply to some of the great points indicated by Joel and Robert I refactored the method as follows which ran flawless.

```
Public Function GetSomeInfoByBusObject(ByVal SomeID As String) As IList
Dim strSQL As String = "InLine SQL"
Dim ci As BusObject
Dim list As New GenList(Of BusObject)
Dim cn As New SqlConnection(
    ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("ConnectionString"))
Using cn
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strSQL, cn)
    Using cmd
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter
            ("@SomeID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 2)).Value = strSiteID
        cn.Open()
            Dim result As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
                While result.Read()
                    ci = New BusObject(rs("id), result("description"))
                    list.Add(DirectCast(ci, BusObject))
                End While
            result.Close()
        End Using
    Return list
End Using
```

End Function

Created a nice little helper class to wrap the generic details up

```
Public Class GenList(Of T)
    Inherits CollectionBase
    Public Function Add(ByVal value As T) As Integer
        Return List.Add(value)
    End Function
    Public Sub Remove(ByVal value As T)
        List.Remove(value)
    End Sub
    Public ReadOnly Property Item(ByVal index As Integer) As T
        Get
            Return CType(List.Item(index), T)
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: You can get rid of the check whether the list needs to be created, because you are explicitly creating it at the start.

Comment: You can also instantiate the objects within the using statement:  Using tConnection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection
' ...
End Using

Answer (score 0):

If you were using c# I would wrap the datareader creation in a using statement but I don't think vb has those?

Comment: VB does have a Using statement

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function GetSizeInfoBySite(ByVal siteID As String) As IList(Of CategoryInfo)
        Dim strSQL As String = "YES INLINE SQL!! :)"

        'reference the 2.0 System.Configuration, and add a connection string section to web.config
        '  <connectionStrings>
        '   <add name="somename" connectionString="someconnectionstring" />
        '  </connectionStrings >

        Using cn As New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("somename").ConnectionString

            Using cmd As New SqlCommand(strSQL, cn)

                cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@MySiteID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 2)).Value = siteID
                cn.Open()

                Using reader As IDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

                    Dim records As IList(Of CategoryInfo) = New List(Of CategoryInfo)

                    'get ordinal col indexes
                    Dim ordinal_SomeId As Integer = reader.GetOrdinal("someID")
                    Dim ordinal_SomeName As Integer = reader.GetOrdinal("someName")

                    While reader.Read()
                        Dim ci As CategoryInfo = New CategoryInfo(reader.GetInt32(ordinal_SomeId), reader.GetString(ordinal_SomeName))
                        records.Add(ci)
                    End While

                    Return records

                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Function
```

You could try something like the above, the using statements will handle connection closing and object disposal. This is available when the class implements IDisposable.  Also build and return your IList of CategoryInfo.