# Ado.Net: Does closing SqlCommand cause closing DataReader

Tags: c#, ado.net

Today I looked through some legacy code and I have began worrying. It is required to close a `DataReader` explicitly.

My question is: does closing the `SqlCommand` close the associated `DataReader` as well?

This is my code:

```
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "House_GetHouseById";

            SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd);

            cmd.Parameters["@HouseId"].Value = houseId;

            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())

            while (reader.Read())
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

In this snippet from msdn command is not closed explicitly:

```
string queryString =
    "SELECT OrderID, CustomerID FROM dbo.Orders;";

using (SqlConnection connection =
           new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command =
        new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
    connection.Open();

    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    // Call Read before accessing data.
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}",
            reader[0], reader[1]));
    }

    // Call Close when done reading.
    reader.Close();
}
```

Comment: it might be good to wrap the reader in a using clause as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `SqlCommand.Dispose` is essentially a no-op¹, and it won't close your `SqlDataReader`.

Technically, closing the `SqlConnection` should close all resources, see this question for details:

- [Is closing/disposing an SqlDataReader needed if you are already closing the SqlConnection?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2655978/87698)

However, this is bad practice -- you are relying on an *implementation detail* of the SqlClient library. The "correct" way would be to dispose (via `Dispose` or `using`) everything that is `IDisposable`. Thus, your code should be written as follows:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();

    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "House_GetHouseById";

        SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd);

        cmd.Parameters["@HouseId"].Value = houseId;

        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

¹ Note that this is not true for the command classes of other libraries such as `OleDbCommand` and `SqlCeCommand`, so don't get in the habit of not disposing commands.

Answer (score 2):

You could always wrap the datareader in a using directive so that the command is closed as soon the execution is out of the scope,just like the sqlcommand

```
    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader != null)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                //do something
            }
        }
    } // reader is closed here

reader.Close(); //is another way but its too easy to be forgotten.
```

Comment: Don't know who upvoted this, but question was **"Does closing SqlCommand cause closing DataReader"**