# c# while(true) loop for watch folder seems to cause Stackoverflowexception

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

I am needing to have an infinite loop for a watch folder procedure.  I have it execute a `Parallel.ForEach(iterate.AsEnumerable(), drow =>` method, every 30 seconds, through a datatable.  However, using a `while(true)` loop seems to be causing me stackoverflow exceptions.

I'm wondering if there is a better way to have an infinite loop that could help me eliminate the exception.

**UPDATE 1**

A datatable is filled from a SQL database and exposed in a windows form for the user.  The datatable has the watch folder locations that users can edit.  This is what I'm iterating through. The folders are accessed through a SOAP web service.

Here's the code - sorry it's long but I think you all need to see all of it for context.  Please let me know if you need further clarification.

**This starts the process with a button click**

```
    public partial class HomePage : Form
{
        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                //set serviceStop to 0 (false)

                string connectionString = @"Data Source=FCMONITOR\AVIDAUTO;Initial Catalog=InterplayWatchFolder;Integrated Security=True";
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))


                {
                    SqlCommand setCancelRequest = new SqlCommand("UPDATE SERVICE_STOP SET SERVICE_STOP_REQUESTED = 0");
                    setCancelRequest.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    setCancelRequest.Connection = connection;
                    connection.Open();
                    setCancelRequest.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    connection.Close();
                }


                //start service
                initiateThread();




            }

            private void initiateThread()
            {


                Console.WriteLine("Initiating new check");
               System.Threading.Tasks.Task newJobTask = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                repeater();
            }



        private void repeater()
            {

                while(true)

                {


                    string serviceStop = "False";

                    //check if service stop was requested
                    string connectionString = @"Data Source=FCMONITOR\AVIDAUTO;Initial Catalog=InterplayWatchFolder;Integrated Security=True";
                    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))

                    {
                        SqlDataReader stopServiceRequestedReader = null;
                        SqlCommand getStopServiceRequested = new SqlCommand("SELECT [SERVICE_STOP_REQUESTED] FROM SERVICE_STOP", connection);
                        getStopServiceRequested.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        connection.Open();
                        stopServiceRequestedReader = getStopServiceRequested.ExecuteReader();
                        while (stopServiceRequestedReader.Read())
                        {
                            serviceStop = stopServiceRequestedReader["SERVICE_STOP_REQUESTED"].ToString();

                        }
                        connection.Close();
                    }


                        //check if service was stopped
                        if (serviceStop == "False")
                        {
                        Thread.Sleep(30000);


                        System.Threading.Tasks.Task newJobTask = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                            {
                                executeThreadRunService();
                                garbage garbage = new garbage();
                                garbage.Dispose();



                            }
                            );
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            garbage garbage = new garbage();
                            garbage.Dispose();

                        break;
                            Thread.CurrentThread.Join();
                        }

        }

    private void executeThreadRunService()
            {


                {



                    //iterate workflow across table
                    DataTable iterate = (DataTable)interplaySetupView.DataSource;

                    //execute service in parallel

                    {


                        Parallel.ForEach(iterate.AsEnumerable(), drow =>

                        {



                            //Set Variables
                            string insertDeliniator = "/"; //extra needed to build URI
                            string insertInterplay = "interplay://"; //extra info needed to build URI


                            string interplayEngineHostname = drow["Interplay_Engine_Hostname"].ToString();
                            string interplayWatchFolder = insertInterplay + drow["Interplay_Engine_Hostname"].ToString() + insertDeliniator + drow["Interplay_Watch_Folder"].ToString();
                            string safeForTranscodingFolder = insertInterplay + drow["Interplay_Engine_Hostname"].ToString() + insertDeliniator + drow["Interplay_Safe_Folder"].ToString();
                            string safeForTranscodingSubmitURI = "interplay://Interplay/" + drow["Interplay_Safe_Folder"].ToString();
                            string transferEngineHostname = drow["Transfer_Engine_Hostname"].ToString();
                            string transferPlaybackDevice = drow["Transfer_Profile"].ToString();
                            string transcodingProfile = drow["Transcoding_Profile"].ToString();
                            string storeInterplayUsername = interplayUsername.Text.ToString();
                            string storeInterplayPassword = interplayPasswordInput.Text.ToString();
                            string workflowName = drow["Workflow_Name"].ToString();
                            string catDVEnabled = drow["CATDV_ENABLED"].ToString();
                            string catDVXMLDumpLocation = drow["CATDV_XML_DUMP_LOCATION"].ToString();
                            string xmlMetadataDumpLocation = drow["METADATA_XML_DUMP_LOCATION"].ToString();
                            string rewriteSequenceMetadata = drow["REWRITE_SEQUENCE_METADATA"].ToString();






                            System.Threading.Tasks.Task newWatchTask = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew
                                (
                                    () =>



                                runService.executeWatchService
                                    (
                                interplayEngineHostname,
                                interplayWatchFolder,
                                safeForTranscodingFolder,
                                safeForTranscodingSubmitURI,
                                transcodingProfile,
                                transferEngineHostname,
                                transferPlaybackDevice,
                                interplayUsernameInput.Text.ToString(),
                                interplayPasswordInput.Text.ToString(),
                                workflowName,
                                catDVEnabled,
                                catDVXMLDumpLocation,
                                xmlMetadataDumpLocation,
                                rewriteSequenceMetadata




                                    ) );

                            garbage garbage = new garbage();
                            garbage.Dispose();

                            Thread.CurrentThread.Join();
                        }
}


//another class where the runService method is

        public class runService
        {

            public static void executeWatchService(
                string interplayEngineHostname,
                string interplayWatchFolder,
                string safeForTranscodingFolder,
                string safeForTranscodingSubmitURI,
                string transcodingProfile,
                string transferEngineHostname,
                string transferPlaybackDevice,
                string interplayUsername,
                string interplayPassword,
                string workflowName,
                string catDVEnabled,
                string catDVXMLDumpLocation,
                string xmlMetadataDumpLocation,
                string rewriteSequenceMetadata

                )


            {

                {

                    {





                        //Find if there is a new sequence
                        //If none, method exits
                        WatchForNewSequence watchForNewSequence = new WatchForNewSequence();
                        WatchForNewSequence.returnMOBIDandJobName MOBIDandJobNameResults = watchForNewSequence.searchForNewSequence(
                                interplayWatchFolder,
                                interplayUsername,
                                interplayPassword,
                                workflowName,
                                safeForTranscodingFolder);
                        string returnOriginalSequenceMOBID = MOBIDandJobNameResults.returnOriginalSequenceMOBID;
                        string returnJobName = MOBIDandJobNameResults.returnJobName;


//another class where the WatchForNewSequence method is

    class WatchForNewSequence
    {

        public struct returnMOBIDandJobName
        {
            public string returnOriginalSequenceMOBID;
            public string returnJobName;
        }


        public returnMOBIDandJobName searchForNewSequence(
            string interplayWatchFolder,
            string interplayUsername,
            string interplayPassword,
            string workflowName,
            string safeForTranscodingFolder
            )

        {


                string originalSequenceMOBID = "empty";
                string jobName = "empty";

                Console.WriteLine("Checking for new sequence for " + interplayWatchFolder);
                AssetsPortTypeClient port = new AssetsPortTypeClient();
                UserCredentialsType creds = new UserCredentialsType();
                creds.Username = interplayUsername;
                creds.Password = interplayPassword;

                //parameters currenlty set for sequences only
                //masterclip do not send in this verison
                SearchType param = new SearchType();
                param.MaxResults = 1;
                param.InterplayPathURI = interplayWatchFolder;
                param.SearchGroup = new SearchGroupType();
                param.SearchGroup.Operator = "AND";
                param.SearchGroup.AttributeCondition = new AttributeConditionType[1];
                param.SearchGroup.AttributeCondition[0] = new AttributeConditionType();
                param.SearchGroup.AttributeCondition[0].Condition = "EQUALS";
                param.SearchGroup.AttributeCondition[0].Attribute = new AttributeType();
                param.SearchGroup.AttributeCondition[0].Attribute.Name = "Type";
                param.SearchGroup.AttributeCondition[0].Attribute.Group = "SYSTEM";
                param.SearchGroup.AttributeCondition[0].Attribute.Value = "sequence";


                //send request
                SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest();
                request.UserCredentials = creds;
                request.Search = param;

                garbage garbage = new garbage();
                garbage.Dispose();
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();


            SearchResponseType response = port.Search(creds, param);

                //check if there is any sequences
                if (response.Results.Length > 0)
                {

                    //designate that we want the MOB ID to be returned as a result of this method
                    foreach (AssetDescriptionType ad in response.Results)
                    {
                        foreach (AttributeType att in ad.Attributes)
                        {
                            if (att.Name == "MOB ID")
                            {
                                originalSequenceMOBID = att.Value;

                            }
                            if (att.Name == "Display Name")
                        {
                            jobName = att.Value;

                            //The original sequence MOBID is found and returned from the WatchForNewSequence Class
                            Console.WriteLine(originalSequenceMOBID + "...." + jobName);

                        }
                        garbage garbage2 = new garbage();
                        garbage.Dispose();

                    }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    originalSequenceMOBID = "No_Sequence";
                    Console.WriteLine("No new sequence for " + interplayWatchFolder + " -- exiting");

                    garbage garbage3 = new garbage();
                    garbage.Dispose();
                    Thread.CurrentThread.Join();




                }
                //no new sequence, methods exit and program ends
                if (response.Errors != null)
                {
                    foreach (ErrorType watchForNewSequenceError in response.Errors)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + watchForNewSequenceError.Message + watchForNewSequenceError.Details + "at" + watchForNewSequenceError.InterplayURI);
                    }
                }


            returnMOBIDandJobName returnMOBIDandJobName = new returnMOBIDandJobName();
            returnMOBIDandJobName.returnOriginalSequenceMOBID = originalSequenceMOBID;
            returnMOBIDandJobName.returnJobName = jobName;

            return returnMOBIDandJobName;

                //return originalSequenceMOBID to Program
            //return originalSequenceMOBID;





        }


    }
```

Comment: You have to provide a *relevant code*. Nothing wrong with `while(true) {}` itself

Comment: Somewhere inside your `while(true)` loop you might be calling the method itself and of course you then are calling the method again and again and again without ever leaving it what causes the stackoverflow exception.

Comment: Maybe the code in side your `while(true)` isn't thread-safe?

Comment: Could you give some more details on the purpose? Why is a datatable involved? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Can you post complete code which will allow us to replicate it?

Comment: look into quartz.net or hangfire

Comment: Normal practice is that you post as little code as possible that can replicate your issue. You have just dumped your entire class into the question and it doesnt even compile.

Comment: Why do you keep creating a garable object and disposing it immediately?

Comment: Let me try to simplify the code for clarity.

Comment: TL;DR. One note: "I [need] an infinite loop for..." this is almost never true.  Check @Dmitri's suggestions, also `FileSystemWatcher` for keeping tabs on file change activity.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a virtual folder, not a true file system, so I can't use FileSystemWatcher.  I am needing to check the virtual folder through a web service call.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to dispose any objects that implement `IDisposable` and that are created inside the loop. I have seen StackOverflowExceptions caused by objects not being properly disposed.

For example, `SqlDataReader stopServiceRequestedReader` is never closed or disposed.

Comment: According to [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/a/2656052/5175058) I shouldn't need to dispose it, unless I'm not understanding it correctly.